# How can I balance a panel that is unbalanced in R?

Tags: r, panel, missing-data

I have an unbalanced monthly panel data. There are some States that are missing some periods of time and therefore I do not have those periods in my panel. I would like to add those periods and assign them an `NA` value.

I have tried a function that balances the panel but what it does is to eliminate all the observations that do not match for all the states. Therefore, if there is no data for Alabama in 02-2008 it would eliminate the observations for all the States for 02-2008.

```
balanced <- function(data, ID, TIME, VARS, required=c("all", "shared")) {
  if(is.character(ID)) {
    ID <- match(ID, names(data))
  }
  if(is.character(TIME)) {
    TIME <- match(TIME, names(data))
    if(missing(VARS)) { 
      VARS <- setdiff(1:ncol(data), c(ID,TIME))
    } else if (is.character(VARS)) {
      VARS <- match(VARS, names(data))
    }
    required <- match.arg(required)
    idf <- do.call(interaction, c(data[, ID, drop=FALSE], drop=TRUE))
    timef <- do.call(interaction, c(data[, TIME, drop=FALSE], drop=TRUE))
    complete <- complete.cases(data[, VARS])
    tbl <- table(idf[complete], timef[complete])
    if (required == "all") {
      keep <- which(rowSums(tbl == 1) == ncol(tbl))
      idx <- as.numeric(idf) %in% keep
    } else if (required == "shared") {
      keep <- which(colSums(tbl == 1) == nrow(tbl))
      idx <- as.numeric(timef) %in% keep
    }
    data[idx, ]
  }

Balanced_panel <- balanced(milk_state, "STATE", "PERIOD", "VALUE", required = "all")
```

This is how it looks:

```
  STATE       PERIOD    VALUE
California    01-2018     900
California    02-2018     890
California    03-2018     780
California    05-2018     800
```

This is how I want it to look:

```
  STATE       PERIOD    VALUE
California    01-2018     900
California    02-2018     890
California    03-2018     780
California    04-2018      NA
California    05-2018     800
```

Comment: `?tidyr::complete`. If you share some sample input we can help you more. (Use `dput()`, e.g., `dput(droplevels(milk_state[1:20, ]))` to share copy/pasteable example data.

Comment: What would be the point of adding lines consisting only of NAs? What are you planning to do?

Comment: Here I paste what I got from the dput():

structure(list(State = c("ARIZONA", "CALIFORNIA", "COLORADO", 
"FLORIDA", "IDAHO", "ILLINOIS", "INDIANA", "IOWA", "KANSAS", 
"MICHIGAN"), monthdate = c("01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018", 
"01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018", "01 2018"
), Value = c(2165, 2005, 2220, 1775, 2055, 1800, 1945, 2015, 
1985, 2190)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: Well, that particular sample data is complete, but I believe `tidyr::complete(milk_state, STATE, PERIOD)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you do not want to create a balanced sample from existing data (this is what you did with your code above), but you would like to extend your sample with all possible combination of `STATE` and `PERIOD`. This requires one more step, namely, creating these combinations. Start by this

```
library(tidyverse)
data$ID %>% unique() %>%
  expand.grid(., seq('2018-01-01', '2018-05-01', by = 'month')) %>%
  rename("ID" = 1, "PERIOD" = 2) -> df
```

After this, take this dataframe of all possible combinations, `df`, and use a `left_join` to join your existing observations:

```
df %>%
  left_join (data, by = c("ID", "PERIOD") -> data
```

The resulting dataframe, `data`, is a balanced sample containing all IDs and PERIODs. For computations you could mean- or zero-impute missing values, if your setting allows such assumptions on the variable values, and you have a balanced sample in the narrow sense that only IDs with observations for all periods exist in your sample.